# Use GCDAsyncSocket transfer file receiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, swift, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using GCDAsyncSocket. Write an application, which is used to transfer files between two devices, have a few problems when receiving the file:
When I want to send a size of about 60 KB text file to another receiving devices(iOS devices or iOS Simulator), need to add some packet information before data, like this:

2 bytes header version,
1 byte identify data or command,
4 bytes data size,
25 bytes the reserved space,

After 32 bytes is file data, text files or image files or other files.
So, before I call the socket.writeData, I write a NSMutableData,and send to receiver device.

```
    var sendData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var fileData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "file path", options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: &error)

    // TCP_HEADER_VERSION is Int16, value is 1
    var headerVersion = TCP_HEADER_VERSION.bigEndian
    var unPackVersionData: NSData = NSData(bytes: &headerVersion, length: 2)
    sendData.appendData(unPackVersionData)

    // dataType is Int, value is 0
    var dataTypeTemp = dataType
    sendData.appendData(NSData(bytes: &dataTypeTemp, length: 1))

    // dataSize is Int64, value is fileData.size
    var dataSizeTemp = dataSize.bigEndian
    var packSizeData: NSData = NSData(bytes: &dataSizeTemp, length: 4)
    sendData.appendData(packSizeData)
    sendData.appendData(NSData(bytes: [0] as Array<Int>, length: 25))

    sendData.appendData(fileData)

    // send data
    socket?.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    socket?.readDataWithTimeout(-1, tag: 0)
```

Every thing is ok at send device, the problem at receiver device
Received four packets. Every packet size is different, but I just send once at sender device, and socket header is chaotic.

```
    // receiver device
    func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didReadData data: NSData!, withTag tag: Int) {
            sock.readDataWithTimeout(-1, tag: 0)
            println(data)
            // PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH is 32
            var packetHeader: NSData = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH))

            var packetContent: NSData = data.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH, data.length - PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH))

            var headerVersion: Int16 = 0
            headerPacket.getBytes(&headerVersion, range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))
            // headerVersion is wrong, not 1
            headerVersion = headerVersion.bigEndian

            // packetType is wrong, not 0
            var packetType: Int = 0
            headerPacket.getBytes(&packetType, range: NSMakeRange(2, 1))

            var packetSize: Int64 = 0
            headerPacket.getBytes(&packetSize, range: NSMakeRange(3, 4))
            packetSize = packetSize.bigEndian
    }
```

And I found some discussion about read data:
[Having trouble programming streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998408/having-trouble-programming-streams)

In end of the data add [GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData], at didReadData before use data add readDataToData:[GCDAsyncSocket CRLFData], but also not solve the problem.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I know how to solve this problem.

When I send packet to receiver, is like this:

```
64kb ... send
64kb ... send
64kb ... send
// ... send other datas to finish
```

At receiver device:

```
64kb ... waiting other datas
64kb ... waiting other datas
64kb ... OK call GCDAsyncSocket.didReadData delegate
// clear buffer
64kb ... waiting other datas
64kb ... OK call GCDAsyncSocket.didReadData delegate
```

So, When receive datas, need save a buffer file ,when send finish, handle buffer file to real file.

If anyone know how to set GCDAsyncSocket buffer size, please tell me.

Hope I can help others guys, thanks.